# How to automatically connect OpenConnect VPN when the connection closes?

Tags: server, vpn, openvpn

I need to use a third party web service which is accessible only through Cisco AnyConnect VPN. I'm using OpenConnect on Ubuntu to connect to this VPN using host, username, and password.

However, instead of having to manually connect every time we need to connect to the service (since the service is being consumed by a script that runs on daily basis), I would like to set it up once and have itself reconnect when the tunnel breaks.

Is there a way for us to connect `openconnect` client (or any other similar client for Cisco AnyConnect) to automatically reconnect when the connection breaks.

Alternatively, is there a way to login without username and password and store that configuration somewhere so we can automatically respawn the process when it stops.

Please note that this is all on a server, so no GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the options it has. `openconnect --help`:

```
-u,--user=NAME

Set login username to NAME

--passwd-on-stdin

Read password from standard input

--reconnect-timeout

Keep reconnect attempts until so many seconds have elapsed. 
The default timeout is 300 seconds, which means that openconnect 
can recover VPN connection after a temporary network 
downtime of 300 seconds.
```

it also supports a

```
--config=CONFIGFILE
```

---

There are several scripts on-line [you](http://www.socsci.uci.edu/%7Ejstern/uci_vpn_ubuntu/ubuntu-openconnect-uci-instructions.html) can [adapt](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Using-Cisco-AnyConnect-VPN-with-openconnect) to your situation.

Answer (score 3):

I created a script to do this, you must change `DEVICE_NAME`, `SERVER_ADDRESS`, `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD_FILE_PATH` to a file that contains your password

You can find the name of your VPN device with `/sbin/ifconfig`.

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! /sbin/ifconfig | grep -q 'DEVICE_NAME'; then
  sudo openconnect -b -q SERVER_ADDRESS -u 'USERNAME' --passwd-on-stdin < PASSWORD_FILE_PATH
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

i use a service file

**/etc/systemd/system/myVpn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=My Vpn Connection
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=password=correcthorsebatterystaple
 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'echo YourPasswordHere | sudo openconnect --protocol=nc YourServerHere --user=YourUserHere --passwd-on-stdin'

Restart=always
```

then I just run it with

```
systemctl start myVpn
```

Comment: Can confirm this works. I just deleted the protocol section.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

1. Got to your  ~/.bashrc file and scroll to the bottom
2. create an alias like:
   `vpn-up='openconnect --your options'`
3. save then close terminal and reopen terminal

Unfortunately, it doesn't reconnect itself, but I use --reconnect-timeout=60 so at least I don't lose connection at all when the connection to the server fails, and it's easier than constantly looking for the whole command.